# Como Criptografar com o Algoritmo AES usando chaves de 128-192-256 em Java

Tags: java, criptografia, aes

Preciso fazer uma criptografia com o algoritmo AES testando o tempo de execução de acordo com os tamanhos das chaves (128-192-256), mas eu não estou conseguindo encontrar como alternar o tamanho da chave a ser gerada pelo sistema, pois o meu código retorna que o tamanho da chave é 40 bytes ou 37 bytes para as três.

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.security.*;  
import java.util.Random;  
import javax.crypto.*;  
import javax.crypto.spec.*;  

public class EncriptaDecriptaAES {  

KeyGenerator keygenerator = null;  
Cipher cifraAES = null;  
SecretKey chaveAES = null;  
SecretKey chaveencriptacao;  
static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";  

public EncriptaDecriptaAES(int valorKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException {  
keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");  
keygenerator.init(valorKey);  
chaveAES = keygenerator.generateKey();  
System.out.println(((chaveAES.toString()).getBytes("UTF-8")).length);  
cifraAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); // Cria a cifra   
System.out.println(cifraAES.getBlockSize());  
}  

public void encrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {  
File rawFile = new File(srcPath);  
File imagemEncriptada = new File(destPath);  
InputStream inStream = null;  
OutputStream outStream = null;  
cifraAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, chaveAES, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8"))); //Inicializa a cifra para o processo de encriptação  
inStream = new FileInputStream(rawFile); //Inicializa o input e o output streams  
outStream = new FileOutputStream(imagemEncriptada);  
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  
int len;  
while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
outStream.write(cifraAES.update(buffer, 0, len)); //Para criptografar/descriptografar vários blocos usa-se o método update().   
outStream.flush();  
}  
outStream.write(cifraAES.doFinal()); //Depois de tudo feito chamamos o método doFinal().   
inStream.close();  
outStream.close();  
}  

public void decrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {  
File encryptedFile = new File(srcPath);  
File decryptedFile = new File(destPath);  
InputStream inStream = null;  
OutputStream outStream = null;  
cifraAES.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chaveAES, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8"))); //Inicializa o cipher para decriptografar  
inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile); //Inicializa o input e o output streams  
outStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);  
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  
int len;  
while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
outStream.write(cifraAES.update(buffer, 0, len));  
outStream.flush();  
}  
outStream.write(cifraAES.doFinal());  
inStream.close();  
outStream.close();  
}  

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException, FileNotFoundException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {  
String directoryPath = "D:\Área de Trabalho\"; //Se mudar o pc, alterar esta linha para o caminho certo  

long tempInicial = 0;  
long tempFinal = 0;  
long dif = 0;  

//EncriptaDecriptaAES chave128 = new EncriptaDecriptaAES(128); //Passa como parametro o tamanho da chave de 128 bits  
EncriptaDecriptaAES chave192 = new EncriptaDecriptaAES(192); //chave de 192 bits  
//EncriptaDecriptaAES chave256 = new EncriptaDecriptaAES(256); //chave de 256 bits  

System.out.println("Iniciando Codificação...");   
tempInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();  
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {   
String imgOriginal = "veiculo" + i + ".jpg";  
String imgEncriptada = "ImagensCrip\imgEncripAES_" + i + ".jpg"; //Nome do arquivo encriptado  
chave192.encrypt(directoryPath + imgOriginal, directoryPath + imgEncriptada);   
}   
tempFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();  
dif = (tempFinal - tempInicial);  
System.out.println(String.format("Tempo de codificação: %02d segundos", dif/60));  
System.out.println("Codificação Finalizada...");  

tempInicial = 0;  
tempFinal = 0;  
dif = 0;  

System.out.println("Iniciando Decodificação...");  
tempInicial = System.currentTimeMillis();  
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {  
String imgEncriptada = "ImagensCrip\imgEncripAES_" + i + ".jpg"; //Nome do arquivo encriptado  
String imgDecriptada = "ImagensDecrip\imgDecripAES_" + i + ".jpg"; //Nome do arquivo descriptado  
chave192.decrypt(directoryPath + imgEncriptada, directoryPath + imgDecriptada);  
}   
tempFinal = System.currentTimeMillis();  
dif = (tempFinal - tempInicial);  
System.out.println(String.format("Tempo de codificação: %02d segundos", dif/60));  
System.out.println("Decodificação Finalizada...");  
}  
}
```

Comment: Seja bem vinda ao Stack Overflow, Dainara! Por favor reveja seu código pois, atualmente, ele não compila. Um código compilável pode facilitar bastante a resolução do problema por parte dos nossos colegas!

Comment: Obrigada Daniel. Qual o erro que ele gera para você? No meu computador ele está rodando corretamente. Lá no main tem que ser trocado os caminhos especificados nas variáveis directoryPath, imgOriginal, imgEncriptada e imgDecriptada, ainda não tratei essa parte. Tem também a questão de que para chaves maiores do que 128 bits precisa baixar a extensão do JCE, se não ele não compila mesmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que o problema do seu código esteja apenas na saída:

```
System.out.println(((chaveAES.toString()).getBytes("UTF-8")).length);
```

O `toString()` parece não estar implementado, e parece retornar lixo. Eu tentei imprimir a string e o resultado foi algo como `[B@6a9c98e8`.

Porém, existe o método `getEncoded()`, que parece retornar o que você deseja.

Executando o seu código, com algumas modificações, eu obtive o seguinte resultado, utilizando 128 bits:

[image: Teste utilizando 128 bits]

E, utilizando 256 bits, o resultado é este:

[image: Teste utilizando 256 bits]

Veja que o tamanho da chave mudou de 16 para 32 bytes. Segue o código alterado:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*; 
import javax.crypto.*;  
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class EncriptaDecriptaAES {

    KeyGenerator keygenerator = null;
    Cipher cifraAES = null;
    SecretKey chaveAES = null; 
    static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public EncriptaDecriptaAES(int valorKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException {  

        keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keygenerator.init(valorKey);
        chaveAES = keygenerator.generateKey();

        // Isso nao parece dar certo!
        // System.out.println(((chaveAES.toString()).getBytes("UTF-8")).length);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tamanho da chave: " + chaveAES.getEncoded().length);
        System.out.println("Chave: " + bytesToHex(chaveAES.getEncoded()));

        // Cria a cifra
        cifraAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        System.out.println("Tamanho do bloco: " + cifraAES.getBlockSize());
        System.out.println();

    }

    public void encrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
      InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, FileNotFoundException,
      IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {


        File rawFile = new File(srcPath);  
        File imagemEncriptada = new File(destPath);  
        InputStream inStream = null;  
        OutputStream outStream = null;  
        cifraAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, chaveAES,
          //Inicializa a cifra para o processo de encriptacao
          new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        //Inicializa o input e o output streams
        inStream = new FileInputStream(rawFile);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(imagemEncriptada);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  
        int len;  

        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
            //Para criptografar/descriptografar varios blocos usa-se o metodo update().
            outStream.write(cifraAES.update(buffer, 0, len));
            outStream.flush();
        }

        //Depois de tudo feito chamamos o metodo doFinal().
        outStream.write(cifraAES.doFinal());
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();

    }  

    public void decrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) throws InvalidKeyException,
      InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException,
      IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {


        File encryptedFile = new File(srcPath);  
        File decryptedFile = new File(destPath);  
        InputStream inStream = null;  
        OutputStream outStream = null;  

        //Inicializa o cipher para decriptografar
        cifraAES.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, chaveAES, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        //Inicializa o input e o output streams
        inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);  

        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  
        int len;  

        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
            outStream.write(cifraAES.update(buffer, 0, len));  
            outStream.flush();  
        }

        outStream.write(cifraAES.doFinal());  
        inStream.close();  
        outStream.close();  

    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException,
      InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException,
      FileNotFoundException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        //Se mudar o pc, alterar esta linha para o caminho certo
        String directoryPath = "";

        long tempInicial = 0;
        long tempFinal = 0;  
        long dif = 0;  

        //Passa como parametro o tamanho da chave de 128, 192 ou 256 bits
        EncriptaDecriptaAES chave = new EncriptaDecriptaAES(256);

        System.out.println("Iniciando Codificacao...");
        tempInicial = System.nanoTime();  

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {   
            // String imgOriginal = "imagem_" + i + ".jpg";
        String imgOriginal = "imagem_1.jpg";

            //Nome do arquivo encriptado
            String imgEncriptada = "imgEncripAES_" + i + ".jpg"; 
            chave.encrypt(directoryPath + imgOriginal, directoryPath + imgEncriptada);

        }

        tempFinal = System.nanoTime();
        dif = (tempFinal - tempInicial);
        double segundos = (double)dif / 1000000000.0;

        System.out.println("Tempo de codificacao: " + segundos + " segundos.");
        System.out.println("Codificacao Finalizada...");  

        // tempInicial = 0; 
        // tempFinal = 0;  
        // dif = 0;  

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Iniciando Decodificacao...");
        tempInicial = System.nanoTime();  

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {  
            String imgEncriptada = "imgEncripAES_" + i + ".jpg"; //Nome do arquivo encriptado  
            String imgDecriptada = "imgDecripAES_" + i + ".jpg"; //Nome do arquivo descriptado  
            chave.decrypt(directoryPath + imgEncriptada, directoryPath + imgDecriptada);  
        }

        tempFinal = System.nanoTime();  
        dif = (tempFinal - tempInicial);
        segundos = (double)dif / 1000000000.0;

        System.out.println("Tempo de decodificacao: " + segundos + " segundos."); 
        System.out.println("Decodificacao Finalizada...");

    }
}
```

**Atenção:**

- Eu comentei a parte que abre imagens diferentes e utilizei um código que trabalha sempre em cima da mesma imagem (como teste).
- Incluí um método novo para converter bytes para hexadecimal. Eu encontrei ele [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/1579771).
- Mudei de `System.currentTimeMillis();` para `System.nanoTime();` por recomendação de [diversos posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java).
- Eu testei o código utilizando a mesma imagem dez mil vezes com as três chaves de tamanhos diferentes e o tempo não variou muito, o que é estranho. Então não confie totalmente no código que eu postei... ;)
- Se você puder comentar com o resultado dos seus testes, eu agradeceria!